# I want to format the hard drive and create partitions myself

Tags: partitioning, delete, drive

I have fubuntu installed on a laptop and want to replace it with the newest ubuntu.
I want to be able to create my own partitions during the install. However, there are partitions of the old fubuntu that it won't allow me to delete.
Is there a simple way to just delete all Linux partitions on a drive so that it looks like a brand new hard disk?
I tried gparted on the live disk but that won't allow me to delete the lvm2 partition.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Ubuntu LiveCD, and once booted, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
umount /dev/mylvm/vol
lvremove /dev/mylvm/vol
```

Make sure to replace `/mylvm/vol` with your drive info